Autowiring env var with default if envvar does not exist
I want to make use of the new Symfony feature of autowiring environment variables in a service, where previously i would put them as defaults in the service configuration.
As we build our application, some env vars are reserved to change our behavior only if we need to.
Before i would do in services.yaml
parameters:
  env(PUBLISH_CHECK_CYCLE_SECONDS): '3600'

services:
  _defaults:
    bind:
      $publishCheckCycleSeconds: '%env(int:PUBLISH_CHECK_CYCLE_SECONDS)%'

  SomeService: ~ # for binds

where SomeService contained int $publishCheckCycleSeconds as a constructor argument.
This is a lot of boilerplate which i want to replace with something like this:
class SomeService {

    public function __construct(
        // ...
        #[Autowire(env: 'bool:CACHE_EXPANDED_REFERENCES')]
        private readonly bool $cacheExpandedEntities = true,
        #[Autowire(env: 'int:CACHE_EXPANDED_REFERENCES_SECONDS')]
        private readonly int $expandedReferencesCacheTime = 60 * 60 * 24,
      ) {
      }
      // ...
}

however, in our CI i get errors about the missing envvars:
In EnvVarProcessor.php line 217:
                                                                
  Environment variable not found: "CACHE_EXPANDED_REFERENCES".  

What is the best-practice for this approach? Can i set a default somehow? I am aware that the env-processor default exists but when I last used it, it seems i can only reference other variables as a default instead of values. Otherwise i would try
        #[Autowire(env: 'default:true:bool:CACHE_EXPANDED_REFERENCES')]


but this gives me a different error that the variable true is not defined:
In EnvVarProcessor.php line 124:
                                                                               
  Invalid env fallback in "default:true:bool:CACHE_EXPANDED_REFERENCES": para  
  meter "true" not found

and creating fallback-variables seems to be more boilerplate again that i want to avoid.

You should declare the CACHE_EXPANDED_REFERENCES var in your .env file. You can also set a default value there if you wish, but at least var should be declared like CACHE_EXPANDED_REFERENCES=. If you then wish to set different values based on environment, you can override these in .env.test, .env.prod etc... files.

the .env.local.php file is generated based on vault values, so the .env file in the project dir is meaningless outside of local dev use, can't use that. but thanks for the suggestion

Did help setting default values in .env files? Interesting :)
